# My C++ glm::vec3 array seems to be resetting to null for some reason

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glm-math

I'm working on some openGL code from this tutorial and trying to apply it to my own cube scene - http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping.

Im adding a tangent map to some basic cube code and realise that I had to split the cube vertices out in order to rework them into a tangent normal map for some lighting calculations (basically the help show depth of a texture).

What's really strange is, about halfway down, the nm (normal) vector array seems to be nulled completely by a for loop that doesn't even touch it. My only thought is that perhaps in my loop to change the values of the tangent and bitangent arrays, it's overlapping in the memory somehow. The tangent also seems to have been affected by the same issue and is also being nulled. The pos, uv, and bitangent values all remain intact however...

I've marked where the change occurs with comments further down.
Any thoughts where to look or what might be causing this?

Thank you,
Jon

```
vec3 pos[36];
vec3 nm[36];
vec2 uv[36];
vec3 tangent[36];
vec3 bitangent[36];
GLfloat cubeSet[36 * 14];

GLuint cubeVAO = 0;
GLuint cubeVBO = 0;
void RenderCube()
{
    if (cubeVAO == 0)
    {
        GLfloat cubeVertices[] = {
            // Back face
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom-left
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right         
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top-right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-left
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,// top-left
            // Front face
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // top-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // top-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-left
            // Left face
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // bottom-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-right
            // Right face
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right         
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // top-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left     
            // Bottom face
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,// bottom-left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top-right
            // Top face
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,// top-left
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top-right     
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom-right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,// top-left
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f // bottom-left        
            };


        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            int j = i * 8;
            pos[i] = vec3(cubeVertices[j], cubeVertices[j + 1], cubeVertices[j + 2]);
            nm[i] = vec3(cubeVertices[j+3], cubeVertices[j + 4], cubeVertices[j + 5]);
            uv[i] = vec2(cubeVertices[j+6], cubeVertices[j + 7]);

            /*cout << pos[i].x << pos[i].y << pos[i].z << endl;
            cout << nm[i].x << nm[i].y << nm[i].z << endl;
            cout << uv[i].x << uv[i].y << endl;*/
        }

        cout << nm[35].x << nm[35].y << nm[35].z << endl; // COMES OUT AS 010

        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            int j = i * 3;

            vec3 edge1 = pos[j + 1] - pos[j];
            vec3 edge2 = pos[j + 2] - pos[j];
            vec2 deltaUV1 = uv[j + 1] - uv[j];
            vec2 deltaUV2 = uv[j + 2] - uv[j];

            vec3 tangent1(0.0f), bitangent1(0.0f);

            GLfloat f = 1.0f / (deltaUV1.x * deltaUV2.y - deltaUV2.x * deltaUV1.y);

            tangent1.x = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.x - deltaUV1.y * edge2.x);
            tangent1.y = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.y - deltaUV1.y * edge2.y);
            tangent1.z = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.z - deltaUV1.y * edge2.z);
            tangent1 = normalize(tangent1);

            bitangent1.x = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.x + deltaUV1.x * edge2.x);
            bitangent1.y = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.y + deltaUV1.x * edge2.y);
            bitangent1.z = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.z + deltaUV1.x * edge2.z);
            bitangent1 = normalize(bitangent1);

            tangent[j] = tangent1;
            tangent[j+1] = tangent1;
            tangent[j+2] = tangent1;

            bitangent[j] = bitangent1;
            bitangent[j + 1] = bitangent1;
            bitangent[j + 2] = bitangent1;
        }

        cout << nm[35].x << nm[35].y << nm[35].z << endl; //COMES OUT AS -nan(ind)-nan(ind)-nan(ind)

        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            int j = i * 14;

            cubeSet[j] = pos[i].x;
            cubeSet[j+1] = pos[i].y;
            cubeSet[j+2] = pos[i].z;

            cubeSet[j + 3] = nm[i].x;
            cubeSet[j + 4] = nm[i].y;
            cubeSet[j + 5] = nm[i].z;

            cubeSet[j + 6] = uv[i].x;
            cubeSet[j + 7] = uv[i].y;

            cubeSet[j + 8] = tangent[i].x;
            cubeSet[j + 9] = tangent[i].y;
            cubeSet[j + 10] = tangent[i].z;

            cubeSet[j + 11] = bitangent[i].x;
            cubeSet[j + 12] = bitangent[i].y;
            cubeSet[j + 13] = bitangent[i].z;
        }

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);

        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeSet), cubeSet, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(8 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(11 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);  
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: A memory debugging tool such as valgrind would be very helpful for solving a problem like this.

Comment: If you had used `std::array` and `at()` instead of dumb arrays, you would have seen the out-of-bounds error immediately with an `out_of_range` exception thrown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: True. Unfortunately, all the OpenGL tutorials I've seen use dumb arrays. Inertia, I guess.

Comment: Without using GL, [this similar example](http://ideone.com/25Nc6z) basically shows the error, and how it could have been diagnosed when using C++ facilities (no valgrind needed).

Comment: Thank you Paul, I will take a look.

Comment: @JonathanCain I dummied up a `vec2` and `vec3`, and commented out the `vec` subtraction operation, since it wasn't germane to the issue.  Note that the only place where I placed `at()` is where the suspected problem could have arose.

Comment: You should be able to pass `std::array`s to OpenGL with a slight modification. I _think_ `sizeof` will still work correctly: `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeSet), cubeSet.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);` (note the `.data()`)

Comment: Actually, instead of `sizeof(cubeSet)` you should probably use `cubeSet.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare...

```
vec3 tangent[36];
```

But then in your second loop you have...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
{
    int j = i * 3;
        .
        .
        .
    tangent[j] = tangent1;
    tangent[j+1] = tangent1;
    tangent[j+2] = tangent1;
```

So you're accessing `tangent[107]` and causing memory corruption.  And likewise for `bitagent`.

Comment: I think you nailed it. The out of bounds reads of `pos` and `uv` in the same loop are also undefined behavior.

Comment: That's the one, that was silly, thank you. I changed the i to 12, that's worked perfectly. Thank you.